# Blender crashes when rendering after baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, baking

I've created a scene that I can render fine but it takes a little while so I went and turned off a bunch of non essential settings (Such as Ambient occlusion) lowered the render scale and baked my animations and textures before rendering, however now the render actually takes infinitely longer per frame and crashes...

(On a side note unbaked it takes 2mins to begin creating the frame. With baked animations it crashes before even starting to create a frame...)

Is there anyway I can unbaked my animation and textures so I can actually render my file or is there anything i may have done wrong in baking that causes this issue?